# Add referrer-policy 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin' request header to tomcat 8

Tags: java, security, tomcat8, request-headers, referrer-policy

I want to add the referrer-policy 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin' request header to tomcat 8 web server. Want to set the header in server level not from the application level.